# Use regex to find an list item and use that item in an if statement

Tags: python

```
elementItem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem1)
elementItem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem2)
elementItem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem3)
elementItem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem4)
elementItem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem5)
elementItem6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem6)
elementItem7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem7)
elementItem8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem8)
elementItem9 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem9)
elementItem10 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem10)

list = [elementItem1, elementItem2, elementItem3, elementItem4, elementItem5, elementItem6, elementItem7, elementItem8, elementItem9, elementItem10]

patternForFindingListItem = r"some pattern"

for element in list:
    element = element.text # get the text from each element in the list
    match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element)
    if match:
        print(item)
        element.click() # element.click() #AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'.
```

This is because e.g. elementItem2.text is a string. How do I turn it back to the element elementItem2 again so I can perform a click() action on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override the element variable to get its text. You can simply type element.text inside the regex search function, or store the element.text inside another variable.

```
for element in list: 
    match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
    if match:
        print(item)
        element.click()
```